# Expandible/Collapsible button inside a Table in SFDC lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button, table

I would like to add an expandable/collapsible button beside each row of a table.
Upon clicking the button, a new row will be displayed inside the particular row,and on clicking the button again the row will collapse.
Please suggest the way I can create a function that will solve the purpose.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where does the actual issue lie? This forum lends a helping hand in solving your legit problems and not do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lightning:treeGrid` base component to achieve this behavior. Refer this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/example)